# Map Array of type T1 to Array of type T2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following Typescript class:

```
export class Envelope<T> {
  result: T;
  constructor(result: T) {
    this.result = result;
  }
}
```

I need to map `Envelope<RecentPostResponse[]>` to `Observable<PostModel[]>`:

```
getPosts(): Observable<PostModel[]> {

  return this.postService.getRecent().pipe(

    map((envelope: Envelope<RecentPostResponse[]>) => 

    envelope.result.map((response: RecentPostResponse) => { 

      return {
        id: response.id, 
        // Other properties
      };

    })));
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Envelope<RecentPostResponse[]>, { id: number; }[]>'.
Type 'Envelope<RecentPostResponse[]>' is not assignable to type 'Envelope<RecentPostResponse>'.
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

Initially the envelope was (`result type was T[]`):

```
export class Envelope<T> {
  result: T[];
  constructor(result: T[]) {
    this.result = result;
  }
}
```

And the conversion was working as:

```
getPosts(): Observable<PostModel[]> {

  return this.postService.getRecent().pipe(

    map((envelope: Envelope<RecentPostResponse>) => 

      envelope.result.map((response: RecentePostResponse) => { 

        return {
          id: response.id, 
        };

      }))); 

    };
```

Then I did a simple change to Envelope (`result type changed from T[] to T`):

```
export class Envelope<T> {
  result: T;
  constructor(result: T) {
    this.result = result;
  }
}
```

But I am failing to adapt the conversion to it ...

Comment: i think you should us switchMap instead of map,envelope.result.switchMap((response: RecentPostResponse) => { 

    return {
      id: response.id, 
      // Other properties
    };

  }) because you are trying to return a new object

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually defining the result type.

This is the type definition of map:

```
export declare function map<T, R>(
  project: (value: T, index: number
) => R, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
```

This is how you can use it:

```
Observable<PostModel[]> this.postService.getRecent().pipe(

  map<Envelope<T1>,Envelope<T2>>((envelope: Envelope<RecentPostResponse[]>) => 

  return envelope.result.map<T1,T2>((response: RecentPostResponse) => { 

    return {
      id: response.id, 
      // Other properties
    };

  })));
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it does not work ... Why Envelope<T1> and Envelope<T2>? Basically I am trying to convert Envelope<RecentPostResponse[]> to Observable<PostModel[]>. Not sure about the Envelope output.

Comment: I added an update to my question showing the change I did in my code that made it stop working while before was working ... It was a small change. In Envelope, Result change from T[] to T.